# Should a proper name consisting of valid words be always capitalized?

Tags: capitalization, proper-nouns

Assuming "Information retrieval" is an official term describing a research domain, should it be capitalized in the middle of a sentence? that is, what is/are the correct form/s:

1. I am interested in information retrieval.
2. I am interested in Information retrieval.
3. I am interested in Information Retrieval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's the name of a department or a company, then yes, both words need to be capitalized.

If not (i.e. if you're simply interested in information retrieval as a phenomenon - the act itself of retrieving information), neither needs to be capitalized.